# Delete corrupt gz archives with "xargs rm"

Tags: bash, xargs, gunzip

I would like to pre-process a directory of .gz files before submitting them to Hadoop/Spark. This is to avoid issues, such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40182164/395287) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19523724/395287). The following bash pipeline *almost* does what  I need, except that `xargs rm` doesn't seem to delete the files that fail the `gunzip -t` test.

```
gunzip -t *.gz 2>&1 | cut -f 2 -d: - | xargs rm
```

The pipeline works silently. Yet when `gunzip -t *.gz` is called again, it prints out

```
gzip: unhappy.gz: unexpected end of file
```

or similar.

Comment: Your exact command works fine when I test it with a bogus `test.gz` created with simply `echo > test.gz`. You'll need to provide more details about what's going wrong. Are any error messages shown? What is the input provided to `xargs rm`? What happens if you call `xargs rm` with that exact same input manually?

Comment: It looks like the issue arises when there is more than one corrupt input file.

Comment: Unrelated but, if the data is valuable, have you tried gzrecover?

Comment: @RicardoBranco no, but that would make a lots of sense. In my case, errors are caused by interrupted downloads. Using `gzrecover` could save unnecessary downloading.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it looks as though this only deletes one file, then finishes. A (more complicated) pipeline that invokes `xargs` twice seems to work much more reliably:

```
ls *.gz | xargs -n 1 gunzip -t 2>&1 | cut -f 2 -d: - | xargs -t -n 1 rm
```

Decomposed, this pipeline says:

- `ls *.gz`: list all `.gz` files
- `xargs -n 1 gunzip -t 2>&1`: send that list one at a time (`-n 1`) to `gunzip -t`, to *test* the input
- `cut -f 2 -d: -`: extract the filename from the output of `gunzip`, which is the second field (`-f 2`) of the line delimited by `:` character
- `xargs -t -n 1 rm`: send the output of `cut` to `rm` one filename at a time, printing out progress (`-t`) as it operates